# How can we connect our Azure service fabric cluster to on-premises service/ database?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, hybrid-cloud

We are in process of **moving our on-premises services to service fabric** and planning to host it on Azure Service Fabric cluster. These service will **require access to resources which are on-premises** (corp network) and we currently can not move them.

**What are the options we have?** In past, I've used Hybrid connection for Azure web app but I'm not sure how this can be done for services hosted with Azure Service Fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cluster runs on nodes in a VM scale set. The nodes are connected using a VNet. Regular VPN rules apply.

So Point to site, site to site and express route should all work.

You'll need to use ARM to configure a cluster to run in an existing vnet.